# MongoDB - Index for object update in nested Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

Assume we have the following collection, which I have a question about:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "user_id" : 12345,
    "items" : [
            {
                    "item_id" : 1,
                    "value" : 21,
                    "status" : "active"
            },
            {
                    "item_id" : 2,
                    "value" : 22,
                    "status" : "active"
            },
            {
                    "item_id" : 3,
                    "value" : 23,
                    "status" : "active"
            },
            ...
            {
                    "item_id" : 1000,
                    "value" : 1001,
                    "status" : "active"
            },
    ]
}
```

In a collection I have a lot of documents (as much as users in the system, at about **100K documents in collection**). In every document I have around **1000 documents inside array** "items"

The list of operations that will be used:

1. Read whole document once user logins to the system (**rare** operation).
2. Update a single document in a nested array items and set "value" and "status" almost on every "user click" (**frequent** operation)

`db.items.update({_id : 1 , "items.item_id" : 1000} , {$set: {"items.$.value": 1000}})`

3. Insert a new document to a collection with 1000 documents in nested array. This operation will be done on a new user registration (**very rare** operation)

The question is: **Do I need to create a compound index like**
`db.items.createIndex( { "_id": 1, "items.item_id": 1 } )`
to help the MongoDB to update certain document inside array or MongoDB does search in whole document no matter of compound index? Or maybe someone can propose a different schema for such a scenario?

Comment: The index helps you find documents, not search into a document, so the compound index will not help.

Comment: @wdberkeley do you think it will be better to store each array subdocument as a separate document inside a collection or this scheme is fine for the workflow I have described without compound index? I'm aware that frequent array subdocument updates will be a bottle neck, because each time MongoDB will search needed document inside array and thus will use a lot of I/O read resources